# PHP Fatal Error in cache.php on line 123 $wp_object_cache is non-object

Tags: cache

I use the transient this way (simple Example):

```
function my_url_cache( $url ) 
{
   $transient_id = hash( "crc32", $url );
   $content = get_transient( 'my_url_cache_' . $transient_id );
   set_transient( 'my_url_cache_' . $transient_id, $content, 60 * 60 * 24 );
   set_transient( 'my_url_cache_backup_' . $transient_id, $content, 0 ); 
}
```

Together with a plugin from my company they get this error, when they want to refresh their cache:

> Call to a member function get() on a non-object in
>   /wordpress/wp-includes/cache.php on line 123

**Without my plugin they have no problems**

**/wordpress/wp-includes/cache.php on line 123:**

```
/**
 * Retrieves the cache contents from the cache by key and group.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @see WP_Object_Cache::get()
 * @global WP_Object_Cache $wp_object_cache Object cache global instance.
 *
 * @param int|string  $key    The key under which the cache contents are stored.
 * @param string      $group  Optional. Where the cache contents are grouped. Default empty.
 * @param bool        $force  Optional. Whether to force an update of the local cache from the persistent
 *                            cache. Default false.
 * @param bool        $found  Optional. Whether the key was found in the cache. Disambiguates a return of false,
 *                            a storable value. Passed by reference. Default null.
 * @return bool|mixed False on failure to retrieve contents or the cache
 *                    contents on success
 */
    function wp_cache_get( $key, $group = '', $force = false, &$found = null ) {
        global $wp_object_cache;

        return $wp_object_cache->get( $key, $group, $force, $found ); // Line 123
    }
```

**On my Testserver I cannot reproduce this error.**

They don't use a different Caching system.

The $wp_object_cache seems not to be an object. I don't know if for my plugin or their plugin or both.

**Do I have to use a special hook in Wordpress**, before I can use the get_ and set_transient functions? I use my cache function inside this hook only:

```
add_shortcode( 'feedimport', array( $this, "shortcode_feedimport" ) );
```

**UPDATE:**

The other plugin uses the wp_schedule_event:

```
private static function cron_schedule_event_setup() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook(self::cron_hook);
    wp_schedule_event(time(), self::$options['schedule_event'], self::cron_hook);
}
```

And store their data in a database table. They don't use the get_ set_transient functions. :(

I realy don't know how my plugin can affect their plugin. Full Code of their plugin: [link](https://github.com/RRZE-Webteam/rrze-calendar)

**Update 2 - Solved:**

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->save_log();
}
```

This code starts a function which uses the wordpress caching system.

Changing to this:

```
add_action('shutdown', array($this, "save_log"));
```

Solved the Problem. I never use Wordpress Functions again in a Destructor.

Comment: How/where do you call `my_url_cache()`?

Comment: Inside the hook `plugins_loaded` I add a `shortcode` and inside this shortcode I call `my_url_cache()`.

Comment: `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'my_plugin_class', 'instance' ) );`

Comment: Full Code: [link](https://github.com/shoprex/lnt-feedimport)

Comment: After short read of your code, you get the transient on the hook `wp_ajax_*` that have not the global, not a cache object. You should get the transient before you fire the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you have to be careful when using `__destruct`.

This is a special function that fires when the object is about to be destroyed. When PHP calls `exit` (as `wp_send_json()` does), we do not control in what order PHP will destroy the objects.

So `__destruct` is very dangerous when it relies on other classes. I've seen this causing fatals especially on PHP 5.6, which leads to errors like this:

```php
/**
 * Job destructor
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->logger->commit();
}
```

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function commit() on null`

### The Solution

Instead of:

```php
$job = new Job;
wp_send_json($job->start());
```

Do:

```php
wp_send_json((new Job)->start());
```

Which is the same as:

```php
$job = new Job;

$results = $job->start();

// Trigger __destruct while we are on a known state
unset($job);

wp_send_json($results);
```

You have to do this when the PHP process is going to be interrupted by an `exit` or a `die`.

`wp_send_json()` is the most notable example, as we use it a lot and it calls `exit` right after echoing the JSON string. But this could apply to other functions, like `wp_die()`, `exit`, `die`, etc.

Bottom line, just make sure that a function that uses `__destruct` is destroyed if the PHP process is going to be interrupted, otherwise, this could cause issues.

Proof of concept: https://3v4l.org/GBBIV

[image: __destruct running on multiple PHP versions]